# clear thumbnail image on uploading new image?

Tags: javascript, html

I am uploading multiple images and previewing it by making thumbnails.And when i reupload the images the previous images are alsop there.How can i clear the previous images on uploading the new images .

my html:-

```
 <div>
                                        <input type="file" id="files"  multiple name="media" accept="image/*" />
                                        <output id="list"></output>
                                    </div>
```

my script of making thumbnail image:-

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
            // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.

            for (var i = 0, validatedfiles,f; f = files[i],validatedfiles = files[i]; i++) {
                if (i > 3) {

                    break;
                }
                  //  alert (f.name);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var imagearray = [];
                imagearray = files[i];
   //             alert ( imagearray);

                // Closure to capture the file information.
                reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                    return function (e) {

                        // Render thumbnail.
                                              span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumbs_image" src="',e.target.result,'" title="', escape               (theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');

                        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                         span.children[1].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                            span.parentNode.removeChild(span);


                })(imagearray);

                // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                reader.readAsDataURL(imagearray);
            }
        }
```

Comment: well you seem to know how to make the thumbnails, what are you doing to remove them?

Comment: well what i was trying to do is reset my output list in order to remove them. document.getElementById('files').addEventListener("click",function(event){
            $('#list').val("");

        }

Comment: maybe try `$('#list').html("");` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the html :-

```
<div>
                                        <input type="file" id="files"  multiple name="media" accept="image/*" />
                                        <output id="list"></output>
                                    </div>
```

i will pass the id of output as empty in script:
script :

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
            // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.

            for (var i = 0, validatedfiles,f; f = files[i],validatedfiles = files[i]; i++) {
           $("#list").html("");
                if (i > 3) {

                    break;
                }
                  //  alert (f.name);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var imagearray = [];
                imagearray = files[i];
   //             alert ( imagearray);

                // Closure to capture the file information.
                reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                    return function (e) {

                        // Render thumbnail.
                                              span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumbs_image" src="',e.target.result,'" title="', escape               (theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');

                        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                         span.children[1].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                            span.parentNode.removeChild(span);


                })(imagearray);

                // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                reader.readAsDataURL(imagearray);
            }
        }
```